# C: Symbols not found for function defined in file?

Tags: c

I have a cryptic error, and a warning. The warning: integer initialized to pointer on assignment the other is symbol not found, referring to function popdepholder.

I believe they may somehow be related due to a phantom function that exists but can't be seen or something

header dependency.h:

```
#include "relation.h"
#include "strhelp.h"
#include <time.h>
#ifndef _DEPENDENCY_H
#define _DEPENDENCY_H
typedef struct fd {
    RELATION *left;
    RELATION *right;
    RELATION *referring; } DEPENDENCY;
typedef struct dh {
    DEPENDENCY *data;
    struct dh *next;
    struct dh *prev; } DEP_HOLDER;

DEP_HOLDER * popdepholer(DEP_HOLDER **top); 
...
void removedepholderat(DEP_HOLDER **list,int dest);
...
DEP_HOLDER * popdepholer(DEP_HOLDER **top) ###this function is not being seen
{
    DEP_HOLDER * remove = 0;
    if(*top)
    {
        remove=(*top);
        if(remove->prev)
        {
            if(remove->next) /*the middle case*/
            {

                remove->prev->next=remove->next;
                remove->next->prev=remove->prev;
                (*top)=(*top)->next;
            }
            else /*the bottom case*/
            {
                remove->prev->next=0;
                *top=0;
            }
        }
        else if((remove->next)&&!(remove->prev)) /*the top case*/
        {
            remove->next->prev=0;
            (*top)=(*top)->next;
        }
        else /*the single case*/
        {
            *top = 0;
        }
        remove->prev=0;
        remove->next=0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("In popdepholder, passed a null pointer!\n");
        exit(4);
    }
    return remove;
}
...
void removedepholderat(DEP_HOLDER **list,int dest)
{
    DEP_HOLDER *holder = *list;
    if(dest == 1) #here
    {
        DEP_HOLDER * r = popdepholder(list); #here
        destroydepholder(&r);
    }
    else
    {
        while((holder) && (dest>1))
        {
            holder=holder->next;
                dest--;
        }
        if((holder) && dest==1)
        {
            DEP_HOLDER * r = popdepholder(&holder); #here
            destroydepholder(&r);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

main.c:

```
#include "dependency.h"
DEP_HOLDER *mydp = getnewholder(d1);
...
DEP_HOLDER * a = popdepholder(&mydp);
```

error:

```
In file included from test-dependency.c:3:
dependency.h: In function ‘removedepholderat’:
dependency.h:332: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
dependency.h:344: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
test-dependency.c: In function ‘main’:
test-dependency.c:37: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_popdepholder", referenced from:
      _removedepholderat in ccUGYlgF.o
      _main in ccUGYlgF.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It looks like you are linking the wrong type of library to it.

Comment: Could you indicate in your code (use a single line comment perhaps) where lines 332 and 344 are? I suspect the problem is your setting the pointers to `0`, instead of NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared and defined `popdepholer` instead of `popdepholder` (missing the second **d**).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are attempting to link a 32-bit library into a 64-bit binary. Check that your makefile build process is linking in the correct library.